# WPUF plugin of wordpress, unable to save when put html tags to Custom html form

Tags: wordpress

I am using the [Word Press User Frontend plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/), buut I am unable to save when put HTML tags inside a custom form. My process current looks as follows

1. Make forms on Edit panel.
2. Push `Save Form` for save. (This is OK.)
3. Make a form of "Custom HTML", and put HTML tag.
4. Push `Save Form` for save.
5. All of forms are deleted...tears.

It seems like the problem occurs when I use double quotation in the HTML tag. Single quotation is should be OK. **Does anyone know this problem and how to solve it?**

Comment: I sudden found way, that is putting **Back slash** before **Double quotation**, like this **\"**. This is working. but I have to do this every update forms? This is quite troublesome...

Comment: Welcome to SO! I edited your question, tried to make it understandable and I also fixed the typesetting. Please have a look whether I understood your question correct.

Comment: I have tried with the HTML like: <h3 class="title">Please input information</h3> But it seems all okay so far. Maybe you should consider checking the theme or plugin conflict.

Comment: Thanks B-rian and Mehedi Hasan! Thank you your fixing my bad english B-rian, it is perfect!  Mehedi Hasan, You already help me a lot. I ll post again After I solve.

Answer (score 0):

I got to solve this problem.
See this Wordpress forum.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-use-double-quotation-in-custom-html-form/#post-12404235

**wp_unslash** function in the plugin was effect, but  Plugin builder Mehedi Hasan fixed and  updated soon. He is nice guy.

Regard.